# Fullcalendar returning epoch time values to the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar jquery plugin for my page.When i'm inserting new events using the fullcalendar plugin.., its returning me epoch time values instead of UTC timedate values.

Below is the code that inserts new data into the database on clicking a date.

```
    calendar.fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
        drop: function() {
            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                $(this).remove();
            }
        },

        eventSources: [

            {

                url: '/v1/calendar/',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType:'json',


            },
           calendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', response )
        ],

        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {

            bootbox.prompt("New Event Title:", function(title) {
                var people_id=1;
                //var title=event.title;
                //var start=event.start;
                //var end=event.end;

                if (title !== null) {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                            {
                                people_id:people_id,
                                title: title,
                                start: start,
                                end: end,
                                allDay: allDay
                            },

                    true // make the event "stick"


                            );






                            $.ajax({
                                 url: '/v1/calendar',
                                 data: 'people_id='+people_id+'&title='+title+'&start='+start+'&end='+end,

                                 type: 'POST',
                                 dataType: 'json',
                                 success: function(response){
                                     bootbox.alert("Event Created!");

                                   console.log(response);
                                 },
                                 error: function(e){
                                   console.log(e.responseText);
                                 }
                               });  

                }
            });
```

The event is successfully added into the database...but the time is in epoch format.

the console response I'm getting is given below:

```
     {people_id: "1", evt_description: "testing", date1: "1431388800000", date2: "1431475200000", event_id: 4}
```

I'm using laravel framework at the backend I'm attaching  my CalendarController below:

```
    <?php

class CalendarController extends \BaseController {

/**
 * Display a listing of calendar
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $event = DB::table('events')

    ->leftJoin('people','people.people_id','=','events.people_id')  
    ->leftJoin('people_roles','people_roles.people_id','=','events.people_id')      
    ->get(array('events.people_id','events.event_id','events.evt_description','events.date1','events.date2','events.time'));    
    //return View::make('people.show', compact('address'));
    //return Response::json($event);
    $id=array();
    $title=array();
    $start=array();
    $end=array();
    $i=0;
    foreach ($event as $events)
        {

            $id[$i]=$events->event_id;
            $title[$i]=$events->evt_description;
            $start[$i]=$events->date1;
            $end[$i]=$events->date2;
            $i++;           
        }
    return Response::json(array('id'=>$id,'title'=>$title,'start'=>$start,'end'=>$end));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new calendar
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return View::make('calendar.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created calendar in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    $events= Input::get('type');
    $events= new Events;
    $events->people_id = Input::get('people_id');
    $events->evt_description =Input::get('title');
    $events->date1 =Input::get('start');
    $events->date2 =Input::get('end');
    //$events->time =Input::get('time');

    $events->save();


    return Response::json($events);
    //return Redirect::route('calendar.index');
}

/**
 * Display the specified calendar.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $calendar = Calendar::findOrFail($id);

    return View::make('calendar.show', compact('calendar'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified calendar.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $calendar = Calendar::find($id);

    return View::make('calendar.edit', compact('calendar'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified calendar in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id)
{
    //$type=Input::get('type');
    $event_id= Input::get('event_id');
    $title= Input::get('title');
    $roles = DB::table('events')
                ->where('event_id','=',$event_id )
                ->update(array('evt_description' => $title));
    return Response::json(array('id'=>$event_id,'title'=>$title));



}

/**
 * Remove the specified calendar from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy()
{
//  Calendar::destroy($id);
$event_id= Input::get('eventid');
DB::table('events')->where('event_id','=',$event_id)->delete();

return Response::json($event_id);

//  return Redirect::route('calendar.index');
}

}
```

Comment: So what are you asking? Convert epoch to UTC? Just multiply the epoch time by 1000.

Comment: @A1rPun:I tried that too...But i'm not getting the exact values then too...Its converting to UTC but showing the year  as 4756 and all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    $newstrt=substr($start_day,0,10);
           $newend=substr($end_day,0,10);
           $events->start= date("Y-m-d",$newstrt);
           $events->end= date("Y-m-d", $newend);
           $events->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) to treat the dates on your controller. In your store method, instead of

```
$events->date1 =Input::get('start');
$events->date2 =Input::get('end');
```

use

```
$events->date1 = Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(Input::get('start'))->toDateTimeString();
$events->date2 = Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(Input::get('end'))->toDateTimeString();
```

Make sure to use the package on your Calendar controller. Example:

```
<?php
use Carbon\Carbon;
class CalendarController extends \BaseController {
```

There's no need to install it because it's already a dependency of Laravel.

Comment: I tried your suggestion...Now its converting to UTC but not getting the correct date..the database values of 'start' and 'end' shows 0000-00-00 00:00:00.